# Is it that the threads started using 'new Thread(r).start()' garbage collected the same way as other objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

For doing several tasks like reading and parsing a long file I always a new thread. For example when a user clicks *show scenario 1* which is a long text file that first needs to be parsed,I start a new thread from the main thread that is running the GUI as :

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do the work here
   }
};
new Thread(r,"new thread").start();
```

Like ways I start many threads while the application is on a run.When do these threads die ? I guess they don't die as soon as they finish their work. Is it that they are garbage collected the same way as other objects are ?

Answer (score 3):

Threads are treated a little differently then normal objects by the JVM (GC).

A thread, when alive, is one of the GC roots, even if you don't have any variable referring to it. (We don't want our thread to be GCed in the middle of the long-running process.)

But once it dies (meaning when the run method is done), it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Life Cycle of a Thread](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/essential/threads/lifecycle.html) . Once stated it will (hopefully) enter the dead state eventually. As soon as a Thread is dead (i.e. not [isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)), the GC can kick in a pick it up (if the requirements for garbage collection are met, of course)

To answer your question: Once a thread was started and is no longer alive, yes, the GC will treat it like any other object.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 'GC will treat it like any other object' implies of course the rules for garbage collection. The thread won't be destructed if it's referenced from somewhere else, too. Of course the rules for garbage collection still apply.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can kick in implying standard GC rules. A thread isn't treated any different than e.g. a string.